# Launching A Chrome Custom Tab from a RecyclerView Adapter

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, chrome-custom-tabs

I intend to launch a `Chrome Custom` Tab from the `RecyclerView` like this -

```
public CustomAdapter(Context context, List<Artifact> ListOfArtifacts) {
    this.context = context;
    this.ListOfArtifacts = ListOfArtifacts;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    holder.artifactAuthor.setText(ListOfArtifacts.get(position).getAuthor());
    holder.artifactTitle.setText(ListOfArtifacts.get(position).getTitle());
    holder.seeders.setText(String.valueOf(ListOfArtifacts.get(position).getSeeders()));
    holder.leechers.setText(String.valueOf(ListOfArtifacts.get(position).getLeechers()));
    holder.addedOn.setText(df.format(ListOfArtifacts.get(position).getAdded_on()));
    holder.artifactTitle.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            try {
                /*Intent launchArtifactAuthor = new Intent(Intent.parseUri(ListOfArtifacts.get(position).getURL(), Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME));
                context.startActivity(launchArtifactAuthor);*/
                CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();

                // Begin customizing
                // set toolbar colors
                intentBuilder.setToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimary));
                intentBuilder.setSecondaryToolbarColor(ContextCompat.getColor(context, R.color.colorPrimaryDark));

                // set start and exit animations
                intentBuilder.setStartAnimations(context, android.R.anim.slide_out_right, android.R.anim.fade_in);
                intentBuilder.setExitAnimations(context, android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
                        android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

                // build custom tabs intent
                CustomTabsIntent customTabsIntent = intentBuilder.build();
                customTabsIntent.launchUrl((Activity) context, Uri.parse(ListOfArtifacts.get(position).getURL()));


            }catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Since the method signature of `customTabsIntent.launchUrl` requires the first parameter to be an `Activity`, I cast the context into a Activity hence the

> java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.Application cannot be cast
>   to android.app.Activity

on the line `customTabsIntent.launchUrl((Activity) context, Uri.parse(ListOfArtifacts.get(position).getURL()));`

How do I fix this ?

Comment: it's not clear where you get context from. please add the constructor if you get context from it.

Comment: @humazed - Added the constructor

Comment: can you also add where you setup your adapter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you will always need activity inside your recycle view, I think there is no point in getting Context and parsing it to Activity; instead just get the Activity from the constructor.

so I suggest changing your constructor to

```
public CustomAdapter(Activity activity, List<Artifact> ListOfArtifacts) {
    this.activity= activity;
    this.ListOfArtifacts = ListOfArtifacts;
}
```

and just use activity to launch `Chrome custom tabs`.

```
customTabsIntent.launchUrl(activity, Uri.parse(ListOfArtifacts.get(position).getURL()));
```

---

in case you are wondering what's wrong with your code, I think you are passing Application context, not Activity context.